# How to count id up in sql?

Tags: mysql, php

I want to create a small quiz and I have all the questions in my sql which kinda looks like this :

| id | question |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | how long...? |
| 2 | how many...? |

I want to start with question with id=1 and after a click on a button the id counts +1, so the next question will be shown. Right now this is my code :

```
<?php 
      $sql='SELECT * FROM questions LIMIT 1';
      $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
      $questions= $result->fetch_assoc();

      if(isset($_POST['button1'])) {
      echo '<br>' .$questions['question'] ;
      $questions= $questions['id'+1];}
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you asking about `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that will need to change to achieve your goal. First, your SQL query is almost always going to return the very same record, as `LIMIT 1` tells the database that you want just the first record. You will almost certainly want to change the query to something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM questions 
 WHERE id = ?
 LIMIT 1
```

The `WHERE` clause here will tell the database which record you want.

Next, it will be important to have the `?` populated correctly and, if an `id` is not supplied, default to 1. Something like this might work:

```
$id = 1;
$number = filter_var($_POST['index'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
if ( is_numeric($number) ) { $id = $number; }
if ( $id <= 0 ) { $id = 1; }
```

Now let’s query the database *safely* with a prepared statement:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

/* Prep and bind */
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
```

This will drastically reduce the risk of someone injecting unwanted SQL into your query. The `i` in the bind function requires `id` to be an integer.

Now we can put this together a bit:

```
<?php

    $id = 1;
    $number = filter_var($_POST['index'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
    if ( is_numeric($number) ) { $id = $number; }
    if ( $id <= 0 ) { $id = 1; }

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    /* Prep and bind */
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<br>' . $row['question'];
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();

?>
```

This isn't a *complete* solution, of course. You will still need to find a way to have `$row['id']` set on the page so that it becomes part of the next `POST` request, perhaps as `$_POST['index']` (or a better name of your choosing). However, with some of the tips here, you'll be one step closer to building your quiz site